# Macro quoting and unquoting

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to write a macro to require some namespaces programmatically, so that the result for a passed-in argument would be `(require 'value-of-argument)`. If I say (defmacro r [x] `(require ~x)) then I get `(require value-of-x)` as expected, but I can't work out how to get the quote in there.

Edit: here's a simpler example of my problem:

```
(defmacro q [x] `(str ~x))

=> (map (fn [e] (q e)) (map symbol ["x" "y" "z"]))
=> ("x" "y" "z")
```

however,

```
(defmacro q [x] `(str '~x))

=> (map (fn [e] (q e)) (map symbol ["x" "y" "z"]))
=> ("e" "e" "e")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to quote the argument again, like this:

```
(defmacro r [x] `(require '~x))
```

It should do the trick.

EDIT: The above won't work since x isn't known at compile time, when the macro is expanded.

However, now that I think about it, why not just call require directly, without a macro?

This seems to work:

```
(require (symbol "clojure.walk"))
```

Does that help?

Comment: I tried that before, but here's what happens (simpler example):  (defmacro q [x] `(str '~x))  then (def r (symbol "qwe")), (q r) => "r" ... or  (map (fn [e] (q e)) (map symbol ["x" "y" "z"])) => ("e" "e" "e") - whereas, if I do (defmacro q [x] `(str ~x)), then  (map (fn [e] (q e)) (map symbol ["x" "y" "z"])) => ("x" "y" "z") as expected, but how do I get them quoted ?

Comment: doh - the reason I had gone down the macro route was that I couldnt figure out how to say (require value-of-var) - but all I had to do was say (apply require [v]) - cheers!

Comment: out of interest though, is it possible to write a macro that does that ?

Comment: Not really. Macros are expanded at compile time so the value of `x` is still unknown.

Comment: I don't get it. In the first example above the macro substitutes x,y & z - why can't it return 'x,'y and 'z instead ?

Comment: In the first example you're not quoting x so its runtime value is used. In the second one, on the other hand, you're quoting the symbol x itself, which is why it is returned.

Comment: `(apply require [v])` is identical in every way to `(require v)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defmacro r [x] `(require (quote ~x)))
```